# How to apply properly .fadeOut effect in this slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, slideshow, fade

I'm a newbie trying to make a simple responsive slider. I followed [this great tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/making-simple-image-slider-html-css-jquery/) and managed to add some extra functionality but I haven't been able to find a way to introduce a fade transition to it. This is the code:

[Image with the code in this order: markup / scss / script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuFnc.png)

Things I've tried already (please read the code to understand what I mean):

- slides.hide('fade','slow');
- transition: display .2s ease-in-out; in the css
- slides.fadeOut('slow') before slides.hide();

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance! :)

Comment: fadeOut itself fades the element no need to again hide it, because you are hiding it, it is immediately disappearing. use `$element.fadeOut()`

Comment: Please provide the fiddle.

Comment: Your fiddle is of more use than the tutorial link, if you only get 2 links.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I used @vinayakj method + some new css (absolute positioning the slides and giving a height to the container) and it worked perfect :)